# Unable to get result back in lambda when querying athena

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-athena

Hi I am working on lambda python to query athena. I am able to query in athena console. Below is my code.

```
import json
import boto3
client = boto3.client('athena')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    query_1 = "SELECT * FROM testtbl"
    database = "testathena"
    s3_output = "s3://somepath/somefolder/"

    client = boto3.client('athena')

    queryStart = client.start_query_execution(QueryString = query_1,
                                        QueryExecutionContext={
                                            'Database': database
                                        },
                                        ResultConfiguration={
                                            'OutputLocation': s3_output
                                        }
                                        )

    query_execution_id = queryStart['QueryExecutionId']
    print(query_execution_id)
```

Above code displays

```
Response:
null

Request ID:
"271d19af-1ac9-446f-b631-f8a0c551bf5c"

Function Logs:
START RequestId: 271d19af-1ac9-446f-b631-f8a0c551bf5c Version: $LATEST
c36222f1-f31b-4f32-8384-fdeddadd68ba
END RequestId: 271d19af-1ac9-446f-b631-f8a0c551bf5c
REPORT RequestId: 271d19af-1ac9-446f-b631-f8a0c551bf5c  Duration: 559.86 ms Billed Duration: 600 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 77 MB  Init Duration: 335.55 ms
```

When I query using athena console it displays all the result.

```
      emp_id
1     101
2     102
```

Can someone help me to find out the issue? any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You wrote `print(query_execution_id)` in the code. The result looks like an execution ID to me.  Why is that not what you expected?

Comment: You also wrote `'OutputLocation': s3_output` with `s3_output = ...somepath...'` above. Did you check for the result there?

Comment: Hi Thanks. My result is getting stored in s3_output. I just verified it. How can print my result in console?

Comment: My expectation is print output data in console.

Comment: I was reading in some github. Results will be always in output bucket in csv format? In python cant we get those results?

Comment: I guess you have to pass something different as `ResultConfiguration` or read the output afterwards from the `'OutputLocation'`. Did you read and understand what the documentation of `start_query_execution` has to say about it?

Comment: Also I can see Version: $LATEST some id. with this same id csv file will get created in output location. Programatically can I get that version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get results of query execution, you will need to use [`get_query_results`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/athena.html#Athena.Client.get_query_results) method of athena client through `boto3` API which takes `queryStart['QueryExecutionId']` as an input. As you can see from AWS docs, you would need to parse response dictionary.

Note, before you do that you need to make sure that query execution has finished with in a status `SUCCESS`. Basically, you need to use [`get_query_execution`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/athena.html#Athena.Client.get_query_execution) in a while loop until

```
response['QueryExecution']['Status']['State']
```

outputs one of 'SUCCEEDED' 'FAILED' or 'CANCELLED'.